# Input não esta mostrando os dados quem vem do banco de dados

Tags: javascript, next.js

ENTRADA

interface EntradaProps {
texto: string
tipo?: 'text' | 'number'
valor?: any
somenteLeitura?: boolean
valorMudou?: (valor: any) => void
}

export default function Entrada(props: EntradaProps) {
return (

```
        <div className={`flex flex-col ml-10 p-2 w-3/4`}>
            <label className=" m-2 font-semibold text-lg">
                {props.texto}
            </label>
            <input type={props.tipo?? 'text'} value={props.valor} readOnly={props.somenteLeitura}
                onChange={e => props.valorMudou?.(e.target.value)} 
                className={`    
                         border text-sm border-gray-100 rounded-lg focus:outline-none bg-gray-100  
                         px-4 py-2 focus:bg-white ${props.somenteLeitura ? 'bg-gray-300' : 'focus:border-blue-400'}  
                        `} />
        </div>
        
    
)
```

}

FORMULARIO

import { useState } from "react";
import Uf from "../../core/Uf";
import Botao from "../Botao";
import Entrada from "../Entrada";

interface FormularioUfProps {
uf: Uf
ufMudou?: (uf: Uf) => void
cancelado?: () => void
}

export default function FormularioUf(props: FormularioUfProps) {
const id = props.uf?.id

```
const [nomeUf, setNomeUf] = useState(props.uf?.nomeUf?? '')
const [sigla, setSigla] = useState(props.uf?.sigla?? '')

return (
    <div className={`
        bg-blue-200   w-2/5  rounded-md border-8 shadow-2xl ml-10 mr-10 
    `}  >
        {id? (
            <Entrada texto="Código" somenteLeitura valor={id} />
        ) : false}
        <Entrada texto="Nome "  valor={nomeUf}  valorMudou={setNomeUf} />
        <Entrada texto="Sigla "  valor={sigla}  valorMudou={setSigla}/>
        <div className="flex items-end justify-end m-3 ">
            <Botao cor={`${id? 'green' : 'blue'}`} className="mr-2" onClick={() => props.ufMudou?.(new Uf(nomeUf, sigla, id))}>
                {id ? 'Alterar' : 'Salvar'}
            </Botao>
            <Botao cor="gray" onClick={props.cancelado}>
                Cancelar
            </Botao>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

espero que esteja bem.

Analisando aqui.. já te indico a não utilizar ternary no valor inicial do useState. se caso desejar alimentar o estado então use o useEffect.

Talvez o código der certo:

```js
  export default function Entrada(props: EntradaProps) { 
    return (
      <div className={`flex flex-col ml-10 p-2 w-3/4`}>
         <label className=" m-2 font-semibold text-lg">
           {props.texto}
         </label>
         <input 
            type={props.tipo ?? 'text'} 
            value={props.valor} 
            readOnly={props.somenteLeitura}
            onChange={e => props.valorMudou?.(e.target.value)}
          />
      </div>
  )}
```

```js
export default function FormularioUf(props: FormularioUfProps) {
  const [nomeUf, setNomeUf] = useState('' as string)
  const [sigla, setSigla] = useState('' as string)

  useEffect(() => {
    setNomeUf(props?.uf?.nomeUf ?? '');
    setSigla(props?.uf?.sigla ?? '');
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <>
     {nomeUf && sigla ? (
       <div className={`bg-blue-200 w-2/5 rounded-md border-8 shadow-2xl ml-10 mr-10`}>
         {id ? (
           <Entrada texto="Código" somenteLeitura valor={id} />
         ) : false}
         <Entrada texto="Nome " valor={nomeUf} valorMudou={setNomeUf} />
         <Entrada texto="Sigla " valor={sigla} valorMudou={setSigla}/>
         <div className="flex items-end justify-end m-3 ">
           <Botao cor={`${id ? 'green' : 'blue'}`} className="mr-2" onClick={() => props.ufMudou?.(new Uf(nomeUf, sigla, id))}>
             {props.uf?.id ? 'Alterar' : 'Salvar'}
           </Botao>
           <Botao cor="gray" onClick={props.cancelado}>
             Cancelar
           </Botao>
         </div>
       </div>
     ) : (
       <p>Estado não foi alimentado</p>
     )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: estou bem sim, obrigado por perguntar.. deu certo obrigado denovo